# Are there any disadvantages using Ubuntu only for one dedicated task?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arch-linux

I am modifying an RC car for autonomous driving. All processes like sensor input or computations are handled by the ROS platform currently running on Ubuntu on my laptop.

This is working fine so far. Are there any advantages using a different OS than Ubuntu, like Archlinux, or even creating building my own distro for this purpose?

Answer (score 4):

A Linux distribution is a package of:

- Linux kernel
- A package management system (optional)
- GNU tools
- libraries
- additional software
- desktop environment (optional)

Some distributions are more conservative and others are always trying to be on the bleeding edge, so they choose the versions of the kernel, libraries and software accordingly to those policies.

For a project like yours, you should go to the most reliable and tested  software instead of trying to go with the latest versions, because newer versions usually come with bugs that the developers solve periodically until they launch a new version and then the cycle repeats.

The distribution maintainers publish periodically updates to their distribution, mainly security-related updates. You have to be sure that those updates don't disrupt your system.

Debian, for example, is one of the distributions that packs software that they have certified to be reliable and publish updates that doesn't change the version originally published.

The rolling release distributions as Arch go constantly to the latest versions, so there are more chances that an update can render your system unusable or at least bring bugs to it.

Comment: While stable usually is preferable you would have to take the actual goals into account. If realtime operations are needed or the target is to use a SoC instead of a whole Notebook the requirements would be fundamentally different and might favor other distributions. Though as a general explanation that answer is really nice.